# Running strncat on MacOS 11.6.1

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I am on MacOS 11.6.1 and want to append a character to a string and copied the following from there: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-append-a-character-to-a-string-in-c/

I am supposed to have the following ouptut:

```
Original String: Geek
Character to be appended: s
Appended String: Geeks
```

but only got the following one (with the last line missing)

```
Original String: Geek
Character to be appended: s
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code

```
// C program to Append a Character to a String

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    // declare and initialize string
    char str[6] = "Geek";

    // declare and initialize char
    char ch = 's';

    // print string
    printf("Original String: %s\n", str);
    printf("Character to be appended: %c\n", ch);

    // append ch to str
    strncat(str, &ch, 1);

    // print string
    printf("Appended String: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Like all other string functions, all string arguments must be actual null-terminated strings. For your case you could do a single assignment (`str[strlen(str)] = ch;`) to solve your problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “all string arguments must be actual null-terminated strings”: The second argument to `strncat` is not required to be a string. The C standard’s specification of `strncat` merely calls it an array (pointed to by the argument), not a string. In `strncat(str, &ch, 1);`, `&ch` merely needs to be the address of 1 character, null or not, since `strncat` will take at most 1 character from it, and it always appends a terminating null to the destination string even if it stopped early because the the count rather than because of a null character in the source string.

Comment: This does not reproduce for me; I get all three expected lines of output. I suspect some error in how you are obtaining the output.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. And I tried it on 3 very different patforms and it works fine on all 3 of them. Are you sure the code you run is the code you compiled from the source you show here? Did you try to debug this with your debugger?

Comment: Anyway try this: `char ch = 's';` -> `char ch[] = "s";` and `...%c\n", ch);` -> `...%c\n", *ch);` and `strncat(str, &ch, 1);` -> `strncat(str, ch, 1);` and tell us what happens.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on Mac OS 10.13.6 using both clang 15.0.0 and gcc 12.0.1 -- but only when compiled as `C`.  If I compile/link as `C++` using clang++ or g++ the code works as expected.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I use gcc as a compiler

Comment: @G.M.: That is odd, as the code in the question should produce the expected output shown. How are you running the program? In Terminal or in some IDE? Is the IDE output obscured or limited in any way, such as window size? Is the output the same if you replace the program’s code with three `printf` statements that printed the expected output?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I just saved the OP's code to a file and built at the command line using `clang -Werror -Wall -xc filename.c` -- no IDE.  Running the code results in a SIGABRT at the `strncat` call.  Simply replacing the `strncat` call with `str[strlen(str)] = ch; str[strlen(str)] = '\0';` 'fixes' the issue and results in the correct/expected behaviour.  Something odd with the implementation of `strncat` in `/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib`?  I'll admit to being a bit lost at this point.

Comment: @G.M.: I suspect this might be a Clang or header bug. Changing `str` to `char str[] = "Geek\0xxxx";` results in a crash for me, but then changing the `strncat` to `(strncat)(str, &ch, 1);`, which forces a function to be used rather than a macro defined in the header, produces the expected output. I am using macOS 10.14.6 with Clang 11.0.0.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Indeed, I can confirm that forcing the function use via `(strncat)(...` results in the expected output.  A quick 'dig' appears to show the macro being picked up from `/usr/include/secure/_string.h` as `#define strncat(dest, ...) __builtin___strncat_chk (dest, __VA_ARGS__, __darwin_obsz (dest))` .

Comment: @G.M.: I am stepping through `__builtin___strncat_chk` now. It is reporting “detected source and destination buffer overlap”! With plain `strncat`, `__builtin___strncat_chk` is called. With `(strncat)`, `strncat` is called, so that explains the difference. Is there a bug in `__builtin___strncat_chk`? Or how the compiler is calling it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Likewise.  I assumed `__builtin___strncat_chk ` was doing something like that so I swapped the order of the `str` and `ch` declarations and the problem disappears.

Comment: @G.M.: It looks like a bug in `__builtin___strn_chk`. It calls `__chk_overlap` to ask whether six characters starting at its first argument overlap 2 characters starting at its second argument. But it only needs 1 character from its first argument. The compiler put `ch` just before `str` in memory, so two characters from `ch` goes into `str`.

Comment: @ecjb: Congratulations, it is very rare for somebody learning C or any established programming language to discover a bug like this in the fundamental parts of the language.

Comment: @EricPostpischil:  I am honoured !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `strncat`, specifically in the `__builtin___strn_chk` routine used to implement it. Consider this extract of the code in the question:

```
char str[6] = "Geek";
char ch = 's';
strncat(str, &ch, 1);
```

As it happens, the compiler puts `ch` immediately before `str` in memory. Examining the assembly output of compilation shows `strncat` is implemented with a call to `__builtin___strn_chk`. Stepping through `__builtin___strn_chk` in a debugger shows it calls `__chk_overlap` to check whether the source and destination buffers overlap. For this call, it passes the address of `str` with a length of six (the four characters in it plus the new character to be concatenated and a terminating null character after that) and the address of `ch` with a length of two.

This length of two is incorrect; `strncat` or `__builtin___strn_chk` should take only one character from `ch`.  This is a mistake in `__builtin___strn_chk`; it should pass a length of 1, not 2. `__chk_overlap` correctly determines the buffers it was passed overlap and generates a trap.

This can be reliably reproduced with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    char buffer[] = "xabc\0\0";
    strncat(buffer+1, buffer, 1);
}
```

`__builtin___strncat_chk` is used because `<string.h>` includes a header `secure/_string.h` which defines `strncat` as a macro:

```
#define strncat(dest, ...) \
        __builtin___strncat_chk (dest, __VA_ARGS__, __darwin_obsz (dest))
```

So we can work around the bug by replacing `strncat` with `(strncat)`, which forces the `strncat` function to be used instead of the macro. One could also use `#undef strncat` after including `<string.h>`.

Comment: So the expanation is well over my head but it works for me by replacing `strncat` with `(srrncat)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, following the comment of Some programmer dude and Eric Postpischil and using strcpy() instead of strncat I could solve the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char str[6] = "Geek";
    char ch = 's';

    size_t lenstr = strlen(str);
    char *str2 = malloc(lenstr + 1 + 1);
    
    strcpy(str2, str);
    str2[lenstr] = ch;
    str2[lenstr + 1] = '\0';

    printf("Original String: %s\n", str);
    printf("Character to be appended: %c\n", ch);

    printf("Appended String: %s\n", str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the problem as it does not explain why the expected output from the original code was not obtained, as it should be.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I know. How shall I modify the original code?

Comment: The original code does not appear to be in error. The problem to be solved is figuring out why the program was not executed correctly or why its output was not displayed correctly.